# (.Copy) Destination: = Empty

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having issues with my VBA Code where I'm getting, "Run-time error '1004' unable to get the Select property of the Range class". I have no clue why this is happening, and I desperately need help. As far as I can tell I'm doing everything right according to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837760.aspx . Although I could be overlooking something as I've been making tiny tweeks to the code over and over again for the past couple of hours.

```
Sheets(1).Range("A6").CurrentRegion.Select.Copy _
Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Supplier").Range("A6")
```

When I hover over Destination: it shows as Destination = Empty.
Please let me know if any of you have any insight.

Thanks,

Comment: What workbook are you copying from?

Comment: Another workbook named ("Supplier Tab.xls"), and it's the activeworkbook. If I change the code to read ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A6").CurrentRegion.Select.Copy _
Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Supplier").Range("A6") then I get a runtime error 424 Object Required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the "CurrentRegion.Select" statement and this should work:

```
Sheets(1).Range("A6").Copy _
Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Supplier").Range("A6")
```

Using PasteSpecial:

```
Sheets("Data").Range("A6").CurrentRegion.Copy
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Supplier").Range("A6").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Comment: Hey Socii, Thanks for the quick reply. I actually need .CurrentRegion as I want to select all data within my table, but Removing .Select though worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: There is one follow up question I have. Does the Destination:= function give you the option to paste as values? I'm pasting into a table, and I need it to remain as a table, and pasting over the headers erases my table.

Comment: Never mind, it seems that if I paste over the headers at all even with values I end up erasing the Table format. Any possible solutions for this issue?

Comment: ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("Supplier_Tab.xls_Raw").Copy _
            Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Supplier").Range("Supplier_Raw") Done!!! Now does anyone know how to Destination:= as value?

Comment: I've just updated the code to include an example using PasteValues.

Comment: Thanks Socii, Does this ultimately mean that Destination:= doesn't give you the option to do paste value? I'm new to excel VBA and wanted to know the limitation of the Method.

Comment: I may be wrong (I'm fairly new to VBA), but I don't think the Destination:= method allows PasteSpecial http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837760%28v=office.15%29.aspx. The only only method I know is to use the Range.PasteSpecial method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839476%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Comment: yeah, as far as I can tell you're right it only pastes as is.